# ThreeJS: Get object position vector without rotation

Tags: three.js

So, I'm staring myself blind on this problem and the solution is probably dead easy. I just can't see it.

tl;dr: I need to know on which axis my Object3D instance has moved, completely disregarding orientation.

```
// Init code.
let last_position = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);

// Update code (called every frame)
if (object.position.distanceTo(last_position) > 0) {
    // The object has moved.
    let delta = object.position.clone().sub(last_position);

    // ... what do I do now?
    // - The object can rotate around its Y-axis. (looking around)
    // - I'm trying to "remove" the rotation from the delta vector.

    // Desired result:
    if (delta.z > 0) // Object moved forward!
    if (delta.z < 0) // Object moved backward!
    if (delta.x > 0) // Object moved right
    if (delta.x < 0) // Object moved left
}
last_position = object.position.clone();
```

Basically, all I'm trying to accomplish is to effectively 'remove' the rotation from the delta vector. It's basically how Object3D.translateX/Y/Z functions work, but instead of updating the object, I'm trying to read these values.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the basis of the delta vector from world space to object space (local space).

The `THREE.Object3D.matrixWorld`, which is computed every time the scene graph is updated, represent the transformation from object space to world space.

To get the transformation from world space to object space, you need to [invert the matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Methods_of_matrix_inversion).

In your case, we're only interested in the rotation/scaling which is the upper-left 3x3 matrix of the `matrixWorld`.

So I would do something like this, step by step:

```
// compute delta ...

// transform delta in local space
var localToWorld = obj.matrixWorld;
var localToWorldRot = new THREE.Matrix3().setFromMatrix4(localToWorld);
var invLocalToWorldRot = new THREE.Matrix3().getInverse(localToWorldRot);
delta.applyMatrix3(invLocalToWorldRot);
```

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/neeh/w3v9bdr9/1/). (Use WASDQE keys)

---

If your idea is to use this for checking how players move inside a network game so you can play the appropriate animation, then I would say this is the wrong way to do for the following reasons :

- This is computationally intensive
- This does not rely on an explicit action based on the player (you might end up with character randomly strafing, because some packets were lost, or delayed)

Instead, you should consider sending opcodes for strafing/rotating, and using some sort of motion prediction such that the client can see units moving smoothly.

You may want to [read this](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking).

Comment: YES! If I could give you a thousand upvotes, I'd do it. This is EXACTLY what I was after! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Glad it helped. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I bet what you're looking for is [`THREE.Object3D.getWorldPosition`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r87/src/core/Object3D.js#L412-L420).

This function will give you the world position of an object, regardless of its rotation, and the rotation of its parent.

---

I can think of several ways to do that, here's one of those:

- Disable automatic scene graph update with `scene.autoUpdate = false`
- In your render loop:

  1. Update the position of your objects
  2. Update the scene graph with `scene.updateMatrixWorld()`
  3. Compute the delta position with the following function
  4. Do something with the delta

Here's the code for `computeDelta`:

```
function computeDelta(obj) {
    if (!obj.userData.lastPosition) {
        obj.userData.lastPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
        obj.getWorldPosition(obj.userData.lastPosition);
    }
    if (!obj.userData.delta) {
        obj.userData.delta = new THREE.Vector3();
    }
    obj.userData.delta.copy(obj.userData.lastPosition);
    obj.getWorldPosition(obj.userData.lastPosition);
    return obj.userData.delta.sub(obj.userData.lastPosition).negate();
}
```

Note that the computations for each object are saved in `userData`. It's a bad thing to call `THREE.Vector3.clone()` every frame because it will create a new vector.

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m88u7gtq/).

---

This function is not really convenient when you have to compute the delta of several objects. In this case, computing the delta in `obj.onBeforeRender` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Okay I might have missed your point. But I think I understand what you want. You want to know if the object is going backwards in its local space = with respect to its current rotation. Let me know I'll write a new answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but yeah that is indeed what I want :D

To be more precise. I'm writing a third person game. I need to know if a player is strafing left/right or moving forward/backward, etc. so I can play the correct animations on the player models. That's what I meant by "removing" the rotation from the equation. I think I wasn't clear enough. Sorry about that.It's something with player.position vector transformed by player.rotation.y.

Comment: To be precise:

I need a way to determine if a player is strafing left/right, moving forward or backward solely based on position delta and rotation. I currently have a workaround to trigger the code that handles the animations based on keyboard input, but this will of course never work when I start working on multiplayer features.